# How to filter by using @Query in NestJS and Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, nestjs

I try to filter by category my article from my mongodb by using @Query.

This is my request in postman : "localhost:3000/articles?category=mobilier" but it doesn't give me only article filter by mobilier.

This is my code :

articles.controllers.ts

```
import { Body, Controller, Delete, Get, Param, Patch, Post, Query } from '@nestjs/common';

import { ArticlesService } from './articles.service';
import { Article } from './articles.model'

@Controller('articles')
export class ArticlesController {
    constructor(private readonly articlesService: ArticlesService) {}

    // CREATE REQ @GET(PARAM:CATEGORY) LIST ONLY CATEGORY 
    @Get()
     filterByCategory(@Query('category') category: string){
        console.log([category]);
        return [category]
    }
```

articles.service.ts

```
        const articles = await this.articleModel.find({category});
        console.log(articles);
        return articles;
    }
```

This is my articles.model.ts

```
export const ArticleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ // Schema mapé à une collection MongoDB et définit la forme des documents au sein de la collection
  id: {type: String, require: true},
  title: {type: String, require: true },
  description: {type: String, require: true},
  url: {type: String, require: true},
  cover: {type: String, require: true},
  content: {type: String, require: true},
  category: {type: String, require: true},
},
{typeKey: '$type'}
)
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Where is the mongodb query you are running?

Comment: And have you looked at mongodb pipelines?

Comment: @MargachChris what do you mean by mongodb query ?

Comment: console.log([category]); This console log prints [mobilier] ?

Comment: @JuanRambal yes

Comment: Please add your database schema to the question

Comment: Meanwhile try this const articles = await this.articleModel.find({}).where('category').equals(category).lean()

Comment: @JuanRambal thanks, it's working

Comment: @JuanRambal do you know if it's possible to filter by letters ? like 'localhost:3000/articles/search=ch' and it give me all product witch have 'ch' into title or description ?

Comment: Yes, you can use regex, something like this: await this.articleModel.find({}).where('category').regex(/ch/i).lean() this will retrieve all the articles that contains ch in the category. Read this article about regex or regular expressions https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: @JuanRambal thanks it's working perfectly !